# AddThis conflicts with AngularJS URL state

Tags: angularjs, addthis, angular-ui-router

I'm currently using Addthis's api to dynamically initiate buttons. Basically `addthis.init()` and `addthis.button()`.

When I open up say the email option or any of the modal/popup boxes options. This somehow automatically changes the URL of my app back to the homepage.

This is of course quite jarring. It means while I have a page opened (that is not the homepage), by simply using add this, it redirects me back to the homepage.

I know this is AddThis causing this, because it's the only thing that happens when his redirection occurs. Note I'm also using ui-router, but if that is of any relevance.

This is a single page application framework, so the redirection isn't a complete reload, its a simple state change with no URL reloading.

First click "Popular Ideas" on the menu. This will change the URL to have ?popular=true as the query parameter.
Hover your mouse over the item's image. And you'll see a share button come up. Click on "email". When the modal box comes up, watch the URL. The URL changes back to the root URL, and the ?popular=true disappears.

I'm currently trying to figure out where the `$locationChangeStart` event is emitted from, but I don't see any way of finding the culprit.

How would I fix this?

Comment: This question is no longer relevant, as I have moved on to use ShareThis.